# Python Hot to use output form one class method in another class method

Tags: python, function, selenium, methods

I have class method `generated_username` which is generate string and return that string, and I need to use this output in another method `new_full_list`, but I get run the whole method not just its output
Here is my code:

```
class Users():

def generated_username(self, driver):
    username = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id=systemUser_employeeName_empName]").get_attribute('value')
    username = username.replace(' ', '').lower()
    username = username + ''.join(random.choice(string.digits) for i in range(3))
    return username

def new_full_list(self,driver):
    l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='odd' or @class='even']/td[2]/a")
    l = [x.text for x in l]
    l.append(self.generated_username(driver))
```

Comment: What is the current output you are receiving, and what do you want it to be instead? Your question is not too clear.

Comment: @Windmill in line l.append(self.generated_username(driver)) i want to append string which is created in `generated_username` but instead of this `generated_username` runs again (try to find element  `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id=systemUser_employeeName_empName]").get_attribute('value')`) and then generate string and then return, but in that time i already on different page, so driver can not find this element `driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[id=systemUser_employeeName_empName]").get_attribute('value')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like `generated_username` to be called on a particular page, and generate a string. 
Later, on a different page, you want to use that earlier generated string in `new_full_list`.

To do this, you could create a class variable to hold this string.

```
class Users():
    user_string = ""
```

Then, when on the correct page (I'm not sure what the rest of your code looks like/how you control the flow/when functions are called), you call `generated_username(driver)`.
We will modify `generated_username` to set the class variable we created earlier.

```
def generated_username(self, driver):
    ...
    <s>return username</s>
    this.user_string = username
```

When you later call `new_full_list(driver)` on a different page, you want it to use this previous value. We can do that as follows:

```
def new_full_list(self,driver):
    l = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='odd' or @class='even']/td[2]/a")
    l = [x.text for x in l]
    l.append(self.user_string)
```

Right now, you are calling `generated_username` inside `new_full_list`, which means the entire function runs, including the `find_element` etc.